# Why is jQuery automatically parsing my data-* attributes?

Tags: jquery, html

I just noticed that if I try to read an html5 `data-*` attribute using `.data` it will parse automatically, whereas reading the value using `.attr` will not.

```
data-id="00123456"
```

- Live example [here](http://jsbin.com/adokit).

Why is this the default behavior? I have certain objects whose fields are of numeric values within a string, e.g. "00123456" and not 123456.

Did I miss a jQuery `changelog` memo or what?

Comment: that is kindof odd.. and potentially a big problem... Might be worth posting on the forums for a more direct answer. http://forum.jquery.com

Comment: A ticket & discussion exists for this issue http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7579

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically
>   pulled in to jQuery's data object. The treatment of attributes with
>   embedded dashes was changed in jQuery 1.6 to conform to the W3C HTML5
>   specification.
>
> For example, given the following HTML:
>
> `<div data-role="page" data-last-value="43" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'></div>`
>
> All of the following jQuery code will work.
>
> `$("div").data("role") === "page";`
>
> `$("div").data("lastValue") === 43;`
>
> `$("div").data("hidden") === true;`
>
> `$("div").data("options").name === "John";`
>
> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value
>   (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise
>   it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string
>   without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method.

So it seems that since jQuery 1.6 the `.data` method parses the values.

Comment: The really applicable piece is just one paragraph lower: "Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method."

Comment: So if I had <code>data-last-value="043"</code>, I would necessarily need to use .attr() if I wanted that leading zero?

Comment: Do note that the automatic conversion sometimes fails e.g. for very large numeric values in data attributes. So typeof for large numeric values in data attributes will stay string and not convert to number as shown here (at least in Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/74g2cu57/