# Error while parsing JSON string using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to read values from JSON string and display some of it's values using JavaScript `alert()` statement. But I am getting following exception in the console.

Please guide.

**Console Exception**

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
...dc=/\?/;n.parseJSON=function(a){return JSON.parse(a+"")},n.parseXML=function(a){...

at jquery.min.js(line 4, col 5304)
```

**process.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //for handling json data
    var json = $("#studentJsonDiv").data("students-json");
    console.log(json);
    $.each($.parseJSON(json), function (idx, obj) {
        alert(obj.name);
    });
});
```

**home.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/process.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        From JQuery (JSON): <div id="studentJsonDiv" data-students-json='${studentsJson}'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**View Page Source of home.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/process.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        From JQuery (JSON): <div id="studentJsonDiv" data-students-json='[{"id":1,"name":"Jack"},{"id":2,"name":"Jill"}]'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `data-students-json` or `data-students`

Comment: `data-students-json`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: then use `$("#studentJsonDiv").data("students-json");`

Comment: Can you log `json` variable and tell what are you getting in console before the error? Add a `console.log(json)` before you are parsing it.

Comment: @Abhas - After doing a `console.log(json)` I see following: 
`[Object { id=1,  name="Jack"}, Object { id=2,  name="Jill"}]`

Comment: @Pranav - That's exactly what I am using. See my code above. `var json = $("#studentJsonDiv").data("students-json");`

Comment: as @PranavCBalan pointed out `var json = $("#studentJsonDiv").data("student");` should be var json = $("#studentJsonDiv").data("students-json"); and console.log should give you `[{"id":1,"name":"Jack"},{"id":2,"name":"Jill"}]` and NOT `[Student{id=1, name=Jack}, Student{id=2, name=Jill}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jQuery 1.6 the `.data()` method parses the  values, so remove the `$.parseJSON()`. You are parsing the object not string that causing the error here. Also check - [Why is jQuery automatically parsing my data-* attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340409/why-is-jquery-automatically-parsing-my-data-attributes)

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null). A value is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change the value's representation. For example, "1E02" and "100.000" are equivalent as numbers (numeric value 100) but converting them would alter their representation so they are left as strings. The string value "100" is converted to the number 100.
>
> When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the string; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. If the value isn't parseable as a JavaScript value, it is left as a string. ( Taken from https://api.jquery.com/data/ )

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //static message
  var msg = "Hello World from JQuery!";
  $("#mydiv").text(msg);

  //dynamic message processing for displaying value in div element
  var students = $("#studentDiv").data("students");
  $("#studentDiv").text(students);

  //for handling json data
  var json = $("#studentJsonDiv").data("students-json");
  //     change value here ---------------^------^------

  console.log(json);
  $.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
    alert(obj.name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
From JQuery:
<div id="studentDiv" data-students="[Student{id=1, name=Jack}, Student{id=2, name=Jill}]"></div>
From JQuery (JSON):
<div id="studentJsonDiv" data-students-json='[{"id":1,"name":"Jack"},{"id":2,"name":"Jill"}]'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The data you get is an Array of objects. You just have to iterate over it, without having to parse it again. Also, correct attribute name.

```
var json = $("#studentJsonDiv").data("students-json");
$.each(json, function (idx, obj) {
    alert(obj.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're parsing

```json
[Student{id=1, name=Jack}, Student{id=2, name=Jill}]
```

it's missing `:` after Student.

Comment: it's not a valid json :)

Comment: @Kriggs - I am trying to parse the `data-students-json` and not `data-students`. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `students-json` in data because that is where you have your json data

```
var json = $("#studentJsonDiv").data("students-json");
$.each($.parseJSON(json), function(idx, obj) {
    alert(obj.name);
});
```